# Why does HttpClient SendAsync have empty content when an endpoint returns an error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

**Service:**

I have an endpoint that returns a custom "Error Details" json object when there is an error.

So for my Exception Middleware class I do something like this:

```
private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
{
   var errorDetail = new ErrorDetail()
   {
     Title = "Some Title",
     Detail = exception.Message
      // some other fields
   };

   context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
   context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
   var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(errorDetail);
   return context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
}
```

**Client**:

I consume the endpoint from a HttpClient in another service:

```
protected async Task<string> PostAsync(string path, string json)
{
   var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));

   var postContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

   httpRequestMessage.Content = postContent;

   var httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

   // if error response I expect to get error details json, but instead get empty string:
   var stringContent = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

   return stringContent;
}
```

For some reason httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() returns an empty string when trying to get the ErrorDetail json.

If I call the endpoint in Swagger, the errorDetail json is shown.

Strangely a different sort of error like 503 service unavailable and nginx returns error html, the .ReadAsStringAsync() will return the error html.

Why is httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() empty when there is an errorDetails json returned?

I'm using dotnet core 6 and aspnet core.

Comment: Is there a length > 0 in `httpResponseMessage.Content`? Maybe the `httpResponseMessage.Content` stream was already read somewhere else?

Comment: Can you show the instantiation of `_httpClient`?

Comment: I tested `PostAsync` and work fine. The error message is returned as expected.

Comment: Is there any chance your web server or a firewall is configured to rewrite error responses? E.g. sometimes an organization will set up things so that any error is automatically mapped to a `5XX` error and/or they will change the body to a generic/corporate error message, or remove the body entirely.